# I'm trying to pass arguments out to powershell from a php script

Tags: php, powershell, arguments

I'm trying to pass arguments to a powershell script from a php script. I can get the command from a powershell promt.

```
.\gen.ps1 -countrycode "US" -state "state" -town "town" -org "org" -orgunit "orgunit" -email "user@company.com" -common "common" -altname1 "altname1"
```

This works at the powershell prompt.

I can't seem to get my php script to run this command with the arguments. I don't receive any errors. 
I echo the command to the web page and it looks good.

```
powershell ".\gen.ps1" -countrycode "US" -state "state" -town "town" -org "company & com" -orgunit "Servers" -email "test@company.com" -common "test this here" -altname1 "Test"
```

the php command I'm using is

```
shell_exec("powershell -command \".\\gen.ps1\" -countrycode \"$countrycode\" -state \"$state\" -town \"$town\" -org \"$org\" -orgunit \"$orgunit\" -email \"$email\" -common \"$common\" -altname1 \"$altname1\"");
```

I have other powershell commands I run from php like

```
$remove = 'powershell "del ./file/fullhtml.php"';
shell_exec($remove);
$remove = 'powershell "del ./file/afull2.php"';
shell_exec($remove);
$remove = 'powershell "move ./file/afull3.php ./file/fullhtml.php"';
shell_exec($remove);
```

that work fine

Comment: That's not PHP code.

Comment: No but this is '''shell_exec("powershell -command \".\\gen.ps1\" -countrycode \"$countrycode\" -state \"$state\" -town \"$town\" -org \"$org\" -orgunit \"$orgunit\" -email \"$email\" -common \"$common\" -altname1 \"$altname1\"");'''

Comment: Yeah that belongs in the question.  Probably need `\\path\\to\\powershell` maybe `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\vX.X\powershell`